# Need help in understanding list comprehension expression

Tags: python

I was finding a memory efficient way to get the unique numbers from a list and came across the below expression

```
used = set()
mylist = [1,2,3,4,3,2,3,4,5,3,2,1]
[x for x in mylist if x not in used and (used.add(x) or True)]
```

This is working to get unique numbers but did not understand exactly how it worked. Below is my understanding

```
x for x in mylist  # Iterating through a list
if x not in used  # If statement saying if X not in empty set as defined above
and (used.add(x) or True)  # No idea what it is saying
```

Comment: Please don't use that list comprehension. It shouldn't be mutating objects outside of its scope. I'm not sure why this has been downvoted, but the code you found is not good code

Comment: I just want to reiterate, don't use this sort of construct. It is a confusing mishmash of functional and operative style.

Comment: You said you wanted unique numbers? `set()` should have done the job . `print(list(set(mylist)))` gives you the same output `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`

Comment: @HjS Except for the order, which will be lost…

Comment: i see, so for the order. oh well.

Comment: @HjSin see my answer below for a similar solution which preserves the order

Answer (score 1):

In `(used.add(x) or True)`, `used.add(x)` executes and returns `None`, and then `None` or `True` will return `True`. Basically it is a work around to achieve `set.add()` in a list comprehension when the item in `mylist` is being iterated the first time.

Answer (score 1):

This comprehension is equivalent to this loop:

```py
used = set()
mylist = [1,2,3,4,3,2,3,4,5,3,2,1]
result = []
for x in mylist:
    if x not in used:
        used.add(x)
        result.append(x)
```

in the comprehension: the `x not in used` part is for actual filtering, and the second part is meant to add `x`s to the `used` set as the comprehension progresses (the `or True` is a hack to prevent it from affecting the filter condition).

Answer (score 1):

```
x not in used
```

This expression returns `True` if it's the first time you're seeing this value. So it becomes:

```
True and (used.add(x) or True)
```

Since the left hand side of `and` is `True`, it continues evaluating the right hand side. This executes `used.add(x)`, to add `x` to the `used` set. Since `.add` doesn't return anything, the `or True` ensures that this expression results in a *truthy* value. So the entire `if` condition results in:

```
True and (None or True)
```

Which is `True`, so it's `if True`, so this `x` is being kept in the list comprehension.

Conversely, if this is *not* the first time you're seeing the value, the expression boils down as:

```
x not in used and (used.add(x) or True)
→ False and (used.add(x) or True)
→ False
```

So, the `add` is not executed *and* the entire expression results in `False`, so this `x` is excluded from the list comprehension.

TBH, this is a rather obscure way of doing it, as demonstrated by the existence of this very question.

Answer (score 0):

The if part is what you need to understand ...you've almost got it.

The first part you had right - if (x not in used).  That will be True (and so add x to the comprehension list) if x isn't in used.
At the start of the comp, used is empty, so nothing is in it, so any x will say true.

But after that, you want to add x to the used list - as you've seen it now, and don't want (x not in used) to be true again.

So the second part - (used.add(x) or True) - adds x to the used list.  It needs the 'or True' in case add(x) is False, which it will be if x is already in the list, and it tries to add it again.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is just that `used.add(x)` needs to be executed "somehow".  It appends the current number to `used` and will always return `None`. Therefore, `(used.add(x) or True)` will always be True, which does not affect the list comprehension. That said, simply calling `list(OrderedSet(mylist))` with `from orderedset import OrderedSet` does the same thing. Calling functions without return values in comprehensions should be avoided.

Edit: see https://pypi.org/project/orderedset/

Answer (score -1):

This comprehension is a very silly and time-consuming way of writing:

```
mylist = [1,2,3,4,3,2,3,4,5,3,2,1]
list(set(mylist))
```

which will give you exactly same result.

Comment: …except the order will be lost…